# Cocos2d: Move CCsprite According to Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a game in which i want to move a `CCSprite` (an eyeball image) which I want to move according to the touches.

Like the eye ball should follow my touch direction but move in particular area. I am new in `Cocos2d` so i do not have any idea how to achieve this.

So anyone please help me to achieve eyeball effect on `touchesMoved`

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement the  `ccTouchMoved` method

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {       
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);    
    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(mySpriteToMove.position, translation);
    mySpriteToMove.position = newPos;
}
```

have a look at this tutorial [How To Drag and Drop Sprites](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/cocos2d-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites)